# How to set django-wysiwyg to the field in inline formset?

Tags: django, django-wysiwyg

I have inline formset. And I use [django-wysiwyg](https://github.com/pydanny/django-wysiwyg) to set WYSIWYG editor on some fields.
When page is loaded, everything works perfectly. I use `{% wysiwyg_editor form.worktime.auto_id  %}` to set editor on field.
But when I dynamicaly add one more form to inlineformset, there is no editor showing up.
Here is form:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'

InstitutionDoctorsFromSet = inlineformset_factory(Institution, Doctor, fields='__all__', extra=1)
```

And template:

```
  <form class="the_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% wysiwyg_editor "id_services" %}
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Doctors:</legend>
            {{ doctor_form.management_form }}
            {% for form in doctor_form %}
                {{ form.id }}
                <div class="inline {{ doctor_form.prefix }}">
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    {% wysiwyg_editor form.worktime.auto_id  %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>
    </form>
```

If I run following js code in browser console - the editor appears:
`django_wysiwyg.enable('ckeditor', 'id_doctor_set-3-regime')`, where `id_doctor_set-3-regime` is id of a field, that I need to have an editor. But there can be many fields, so I need more flexible solution.
I think I need to implement something when formset is loaded, or catch an event when subform is added, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:
{% wysiwyg_editor "id_services" %}
on:
{% wysiwyg_editor "id_doctors" %}